# doctrine: many to many relation with join table: how to add WHERE condition

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, conditional-statements

I have three tables:

```
Clients: (id, name, ...)

Files: (id, filename, type, data)
```

and join table:

```
Clients2Files (id, id_clients, id_files, created_at, deleted_at)
```

in php class Clients I want to get access to all client's files, but only to the files that hasn't been deleted (in sql speak WHERE deleted_at IS NULL)

Now I have code like this (in entity class Client), which selects all (even deleted) files:

```php
/**                                                                         
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="File")                                          
* @JoinTable(name="Clients2Files",                                  
*      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_clients", referencedColumnName="id")},
*      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_files", referencedColumnName="id")}
*      )                                                                    
*/                                                                          
private $files;
```

How can I add condition `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` to this doctrine code? To select only files that are not "deleted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotations you added don't actually "SELECT" anything. All they do is tell Doctrine about your objects and their relations. What you want to do is:

```php
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('clients, files')
   ->from('Clients', 'clients')
   ->join('c.files', 'files')
   ->where('files.deleted_at IS NULL');
```

If you find yourself doing this often, and are using Doctrine 2.2+, you can take a look at filters: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html

Comment: Thank you! this means that instead of `private $files` and all the anotations i will write getFiles() method and my custom select as you wrote it?

Comment: No! You have to keep the annotations, they tell Doctrine how to fetch your data. What I'm saying is, when you want to find new Client objects using doctrine, instead of using the generic `find*` methods, you have to create your query to find objects.